# How to get the uid from a username in Linux?

Tags: c, uid

Suppose I know the username, and I want to get the uid associated with it that's found in /etc/passwd. How would I do that without manual parsing the file?

Comment: [`getpwnam()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwnam.html)

Answer (score 2):

The standard interface provided by all Unix systems is [`getpwnam(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html).